# Random dots on screen while playing game (Screenshot attached)

Tags: android, emulation, pubg-battlegrounds

I play PUBG on Tencent Gaming Buddy. It worked fine until a couple of days ago when random dots started moving all over the screen mid-game, something like static bubbles in old TVs. A screenshot looks like this :

[image: The dots move around randomly]

This doesn't happen with other games, just this one. And it's not just in the game, this happens in the emulator too (when the emulator starts and just before the game is launched). I have tried a lot of things to solve this, I'm at a dead end.

I tried :

- Uninstall & Reinstall/Update -

  - Graphics drivers
  - Integrated Drivers
  - Tencent Gaming Buddy (the emulator)
  - The game itself
  - DirectX (I have DirectX 12 installed)
- Troubleshooting Compatibility with all color and DPI settings.
- Changing the graphics settings in the emulator.

For now, nothing seems to work.

What is happening and why is it happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: Tbh, these are the exact symptoms of a dying graphics card. Odd that you can't replicate with other games though

Comment: Wait... You're running the mobile version on your desktop via an emulator?